# How to import Etsy products into Magento?

Tags: import, csv, export, importexport

I have an Etsy shop I want to transfer to Magento. I've exported a CSV file from Etsy, tried to import it in Magento ut got an error message: "Can not find required columns: sku"

I assume my CSV file doensn't follow Magento's csv format. Is there any solution / template I can follow?

Thank you,
Brice

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @sr_magentos comment. Create a test product and export it using `system -> import/export -> export` in admin. This will give you a template of how magento expects its product import.

You will need to modify your **Etsy export** to be in this format then use `system -> import/export -> import` to import your data

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use magmi importer.
  http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Much easier than magento default importer and fast.